# The runtime parameter of nodejs12.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions while using AwsCustomResource

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

In our project we are using `AwsCustomResource`:

```js
    const sdkCall: customResource.AwsSdkCall = {
         service: 'KMS',
         action: 'replicateKey',
         physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of('CustomResource::KeyReplicaCreation'),
         parameters: {
           KeyId: keyId,
           ReplicaRegion: replicaRegion
         }
       };
    new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, `example replica`, {
      onCreate: sdkCall,
      onUpdate: sdkCall,
      policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
          effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
          actions: ['kms:*'],
          resources: ['*']
        })
      ])
    });
```

Now that we know that `nodejs12.x` is not supported where can we provide the lambda runtime value?

We have checked the props and there is no way to provide it.

Comment: What is the output of `cdk --version`?

Comment: you can downgrade the cdk

Answer (score 2):

Custom Resource handlers were upgraded from NodeJS 12 back in CDK 2.28

Here is the relevant PR: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/20595

Comment: yes upgrading the aws-cdk package worked for us

Comment: How can I resolve the same with my code pipeline CDK stack?

Answer (score 1):

As @gshpychka suggested, you need to upgrade CDK for that. AWS [announced end of support for node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-end-of-support-for-node-js-12-x-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3/) 12.x last May.

The API for [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) doesn't let you pick the node.js runtime version.

It was upgraded from 14.x to 16.x with [PR #24916](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/24916) in version [2.77](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.77.0).

It was upgraded from 12.x to 14.x with [PR #20595](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/20595) in version [2.28](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.28.0)

You can theoretically override the runtime version using an escape hatch, but I don't know if it will actually work. The Lambda code itself might not be ready to run on newer versions of node.js. But you can try with:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_lambda as lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

// find SingletonLambda for AwsCustomResource
const providerFunctionL2 = cdk.Stack.of(invite).node.findChild('AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287') as lambda.Function;
// get CfnFunction
const providerFunctionL1 = providerFunctionL2.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnFunction;
// override runtime
providerFunctionL1.addPropertyOverride('Runtime', lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X.name);
```

Make sure to use that code **after** you've already used `AwsCustomResource` at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue on may lambda stack using CDK.
Upgrading cdk versions resolved the issue:

Following is the list packages that I upgraded:

"@types/node": "^20.3.2",
"aws-cdk": "^2.85.0",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"aws-cdk-lib": "^2.85.0",
"cdk": "^2.85.0",